# BLE Connection Issues with RN4870/RN4871 Bluetooth Module

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

For a project, I want to connect my Laptop to a dsPIC microcontroller via BLE through a [Microchip RN4871 module](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/RN4870-71-Bluetooth-Low-Energy-Module-User-Guide-DS50002466C.pdf) to read some data from a board. I can discover the chip and connect to it, but the connection directly breaks off after about half a second.

In the current setup, I can snoop the UART bus over which the dsPIC and RN4871 communicate, so I can see the RN4871's output. Further, a small LED indicates whether something is connected to the bluetooth chip.

I've tried connecting with a Laptop running Arch Linux, one running Ubuntu and an Android phone. My attempts had slightly different results:

- Laptop with Arch or Ubuntu

  - Gnome settings: Can connect, but immediately disconnects. RN4871 sends `%CONNECT,0,3CF011A56305%%SECURED%%BONDED%%DISCONNECT%` over UART.
  - Python script using [bleak](https://pypi.org/project/bleak/): Can connect, bleak doesn't notice disconnect. Bleak reports no BT services available. RN4871 sends `%CONNECT,0,3CF011A56305%%DISCONNECT%` over UART.
  - Node.JS script using [node-ble](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ble): Can connect, but no services available. RN4871 sends `%CONNECT,0,3CF011A56305%%DISCONNECT%` over UART.
  - bluetoothctl in terminal: Can connect, but immediately disconnects. RN4871 sends `%CONNECT,0,3CF011A56305%%DISCONNECT%` over UART. Terminal output:

```
Attempting to connect to 40:84:32:58:38:1F
[CHG] Device 40:84:32:58:38:1F Connected: yes
[RN4871-381F]# Connection successful
[RN4871-381F]# [CHG] Device 40:84:32:58:38:1F ServicesResolved: yes
[RN4871-381F]# [CHG] Device 40:84:32:58:38:1F ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device 40:84:32:58:38:1F Connected: no
```

- Android phone

  - Settings: Can connect and pair, connection seems to stay alive. RN4871 sends `%CONNECT,1,40CC65FB74BC%%SECURED%%BONDED%%CONN_PARAM,0006,0000,01F4%%CONN_PARAM,0024,0000,01F4%` over UART.
  - Microchip Bluetooth App: Can connect and find services. When a custom service is created, I can read and write from/to characteristics. RN4871 sends `%CONNECT,1,40CC65FB74BC%%CONN_PARAM,0006,0000,01F4%%CONN_PARAM,0024,0000,01F4%` over UART.

Connecting with a phone seems successful, but I cannot conveniently read out the data from the dsPIC that way. Interesingly, it appears that when connecting with the phone, some connection parameters are set, as indicated by the RN4871's UART messages. This does not happen with the Laptop.

Although I changed the configuration of the Bluetooth chip before, the current setup is a complete factory reset of the chip with `SF,2`, followed by a reboot `R,1` and nothing else.